# Reading a text file with multuple header lines and multiple sections

Tags: r, dataframe, data-binding

I have a file that has multiple "header lines" (identical) for each section (ID) and has multiple IDs. see below;

```
IDS:    df-1    df-1    df-1
Date/Time   L   A   Z
yyy-mm-dd H:M:S in  ft/s2   ft
2022-04-28 13:30:00 NA  0   NA
2022-04-28 13:45:00 NA  2.968   NA
2022-04-28 14:00:00 2.427   3.124   22.818
IDS:    dat-2   dat-2   dat-2
Date/Time   L   A   Z
yyy-mm-dd H:M:S in  ft/s2   ft
2022-04-29 10:15:00 1.352   2.137   5.552
2022-04-29 10:30:00 1.365   2.303   6.065
```

This is a tab-separated file, and I tried using `tsconvert` package to no avail.

My first idea is to remove the header lines and only keep the ID lines, split the data at those lines and assign the ID to each section, and then bind the data into a single dataframe with an `ID` column and four other columns for `Datetime`, `L`, `A`, and `Z`.

However, this seems to involve a lot of preprocessing. I was hoping for a better (read direct) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to read with `readLines` and then do the changes

```
i1 <- grepl('IDS', lines)
ids <- gsub("IDS:\\s+(\\S+)\\s+.*", "\\1", lines[i1])
df1 <- do.call(rbind,  Map(cbind, id = ids, lapply(split(lines, 
   cumsum(i1)), function(x) 
    read.table(text = sub("^(\\d{4}.*:\\d{2})\\s+", "'\\1' ", 
    x[-(1:3)]), header = FALSE, col.names = strsplit(x[2], "\\s+")[[1]],
    check.names = FALSE))))
row.names(df1) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> df1
     id           Date/Time     L     A      Z
1  df-1 2022-04-28 13:30:00    NA 0.000     NA
2  df-1 2022-04-28 13:45:00    NA 2.968     NA
3  df-1 2022-04-28 14:00:00 2.427 3.124 22.818
4 dat-2 2022-04-29 10:15:00 1.352 2.137  5.552
5 dat-2 2022-04-29 10:30:00 1.365 2.303  6.065
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines('file.txt')
```

Comment: It's generally the same idea as what I have said above, but the way you implemented it cut the processing time down to 15 seconds from ~3 minutes for my actual file. Thanks.